# Choose user from a list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, moodle

After creating my `Moodle` `newmodule`, I want to be able to select from the list of current users in the system and assign them some other data. It looks like the following:

> `Add user manually`
>
> User `[CHOOSE]`
>
> Car hire station `[text field]`
>
> Car type `[textfield]`
>
> Price per day `[list of prices available]`

I builded the database, added the textfields, the forms for them and the button for choosing the users, but how to build the functionality for getting the users's list and add the chosen user?

I did not find such example in Moodle in order use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you anticipate a lot of users in the system then extend the `user_selector_base` class

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Ajax_user_selector

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, I think what you're looking for is a way to filter against a user ID to save your custom information against that user.

There is a widget that you might find useful called single_select, which creates a drop-down menu that sends POST data when the selected value is changed.

For example:

```
global $DB, $OUTPUT;

$posturl = new moodle_url('/local/newmodule');
$options = $DB->get_records_menu('user', array(), '', "id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)");

$singleselect = new single_select($posturl, 'userid', $options);

echo $OUTPUT->render($singleselect);
```

That will output the drop down box and send 'userid' to the page when it reloads. You can then grab that user ID:

```
$userid = optional_param('userid', 0, PARAM_INT);
```

And use that when you retrieve the data from your form to save the data.

```
if ($data = $myform->get_data()) {
    $data->userid = $userid;
    $DB->update('mytable', $data);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, I wouldn't recommend that route. A lot of Moodle/Totara systems have 1000's of users so there will be a lot of scrolling. The `user_selector_base` class creates a dialog that has a search option.

Comment: Jamie's suggestion was easy to implement, I tested it and works fine, but still the amount of users is too big for that. I would try with `user_selector_base`, but could not find anywhere example for implementig it.

Comment: If you search for `user_selector_base` in the code, its used in a few places.